# Trigger AJAX function on form loaded from mysql/php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a drop down menu that is populated from a mysql table via php. When an item is selected a second drop down menu is triggered using a variable from the first form. This works as expected when making a selection via onchange trigger.

I would like to change this though, and have the script fire when the drop down is loaded and the selected item (set from previous page) is pre-set, I dont want any user interaction.

Here is the form code

```
                <div><select class="form-control m-b" name="id" onChange="get_engineers(this.value)" style="font-family: monospace">
                    <?php 
                        $qry = "SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE Parent_team = $parent_team ORDER BY name" ;
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $result = $stmt->get_result();

                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                          
                        if($product==$row['name']){
                            $selectCurrent='selected';
                        }else{
                            $selectCurrent='';}
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" '.$selectCurrent.'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

And the second form drop down

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Engineer</label>

                                <select class="form-control m-b" name="engineer" id="engineer" style="font-family: monospace">
                                    <option selected="selected">--Select Engineer--</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
```

And the script

```
<script>
function get_engineers(id)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax_engineers.php", /* The engineer id will be sent to this file */
       beforeSend: function () {
      $("#engineer").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
        },
       data: "id="+id,
       success: function(msg){
         $("#engineer").html(msg);
       }
       });
} 
</script>
```

I tried onload instead of onchange but nothing happens.
thanks

Comment: If dropdown one was already set on the previous page then when the PHP is run on the second page you can test for the existance of a value in the first dropdowns $_POST/$_GET variable. If its there load the second dropdown with PHP while you are building the page, forget about the javascript

Answer (score 1):

First, add an id attribute to your first select:

```
<select id="my-unique-id" class="form-control m-b" name="id">
```

Then you can trigger it via the jQuery onload like so:

```
<script>

    $(function(){

        // This will run it on page load to catch any auto-filled values
        get_engineers($('#my-unique-id').val());

        // This will run it when the value is changed
        $('#my-unique-id').change(function(){
            get_engineers($(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: That could work, I will have to get the id value from the initial query ... thanks